# Jmeter calling rest url with query param

Tags: java, rest, jmeter

I'm trying to do a rest call which has the query params like:

```
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/?hasName=true
```

I have to set `hasName=true` in **Jmeter**. I'm getting a **500** and I do have JSON data that I want to post at the same time. If I set the parameters using the parameter tab then I can't update JSON data in the body data. How can I do both things at same time? I tried adding user defined variables and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) the JSON in Body Data tab and put full URL in `Path` field

```
 https://www.tutorialspoint.com/?hasName=true
```

> As a special case, if the path starts with "http://" or "https://" then this is used as the full URL.

Comment: I tried the same way..giving full path in Path ...Im getting a 500 if i give hasName as true

Comment: @user2514421 did you change to POST method and emptied protocol and port fields

Answer (score 0):

Do a successful request in the browser or any other tool and compare the request you're sending through jmeter. Check everything including request urls, cookies, headers etc. If you think its all exactly the same. Reach out to the server admins/app devs to check the web server/application logs to find out what is wrong either in server or your request.

> The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that
>   means something has gone wrong on the website's server, but the server
>   could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.